# Case statement and OR in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone please advise on the below?  I have a number of fields which I would like to use and combine these to get the data in one column.  I am using the following case statement but am not getting the results I expect.

```
CASE
WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 THEN 'Hearing'
WHEN m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 THEN 'Learning or reading Difficulty'
WHEN m.u_long_term_ill = 1 THEN 'Long Term Illness'
WHEN m.u_mental_illness = 1 THEN 'Mental Illness'
WHEN m.u_mobility = 1 THEN 'Mobility'
WHEN m.u_physical_coordination = 1 THEN 'Physical Co-ordination'
WHEN m.u_physical_dis = 1 THEN 'Physical Disability'
WHEN m.u_red_physical_cap = 1 THEN 'Reduced_physical_capacity'
WHEN m.u_speech = 1 THEN 'Speech'
WHEN m.u_vision = 1 THEN 'Vision'
WHEN m.u_other_dis = 1 THEN 'Other_Disability'
WHEN (m.u_hearing = 1 AND (m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 OR (m.u_speech = 1))) THEN 'Multiple'
```

It is the last statement that is not giving the result I would like as if there are multiple fields with Yes then I would like multiple returned but it seems it is picking the first case.

Comment: If instead of a horizontal set of `m.u_SYMPTOM` fields you had a `Symptoms (sympton_id, description)` table linked via a one-to-many table this would be a trivial `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the "hardest" condition first

```
case WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 AND (m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 OR m.u_speech = 1) THEN 'Multiple' 
     WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 THEN 'Hearing' ...
```

Because a  `case` stops at the first condition that is `true`

Answer (score 0):

When using CASE statements, they will function in the order you have specified.

So if `m.u_Hearing = 1` then it will stop at the first line and not reach the bottom one.

This will work for what you require, however list it in the order you prefer.

```
CASE
WHEN (m.u_hearing = 1 AND (m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 OR (m.u_speech = 1))) THEN 'Multiple'
WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 THEN 'Hearing'
WHEN m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 THEN 'Learning or reading Difficulty'
WHEN m.u_long_term_ill = 1 THEN 'Long Term Illness'
WHEN m.u_mental_illness = 1 THEN 'Mental Illness'
WHEN m.u_mobility = 1 THEN 'Mobility'
WHEN m.u_physical_coordination = 1 THEN 'Physical Co-ordination'
WHEN m.u_physical_dis = 1 THEN 'Physical Disability'
WHEN m.u_red_physical_cap = 1 THEN 'Reduced_physical_capacity'
WHEN m.u_speech = 1 THEN 'Speech'
WHEN m.u_vision = 1 THEN 'Vision'
WHEN m.u_other_dis = 1 THEN 'Other_Disability'
```

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: I have amended the query to below and this returning either Multiple or None.  Do I need to go through all the different option it could for each and them in or there an easier way.

Comment: CASE
 WHEN (m.u_hearing = 1 OR m.u_learning_reading_diff = 1 OR m.u_long_term_ill = 1 OR m.u_mental_illness = 1 OR m.u_mobility = 1
    OR m.u_physical_coordination = 1 OR m.u_physical_dis = 1 OR m.u_red_physical_cap = 1 OR m.u_speech = 1 
    OR m.u_vision = 1 OR m.u_other_dis = 1) THEN 'Multiple'
    WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 THEN 'Hearing'.........

Comment: @Raehef please don't post unformatted code into the comments section, you cannot read it.

You say that it either returns 'Multiple' or 'None', where is 'None' specified? Do you have an `ELSE` statement on the end?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you cannot use your first statement again in another "when" like your

```
WHEN m.u_hearing = 1 THEN 'Hearing'
```

Above condition try to use else if it is working and feasible for you in end.

```
Else 'Multiple'
```